# is there any way adding cases from multiple spss folder to only one?

Tags: python, spss

I have more than 20 files with .sav extension and I am trying to merge them with the python code in the file path.

Not all columns have unique names. Therefore, if there is a different name in the merged spss, I need to preserve it and add it to the end of the data. Is there any python code that can achieve this?

I was able to produce a code similar to the one below, but this code deletes the labels, changes all numeric variables to f8.2 digits and deletes some of the value variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pyreadstat
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess


folder_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__ or '.'))


file_names = [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith('.sav')]


merged_data = pd.DataFrame()


for file_name in file_names:
    data_to_append, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name))
    merged_data = pd.concat([merged_data, data_to_append], axis=0)


now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
output_file_name = f'{date_time}.sav'


spss_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, output_file_name)
pyreadstat.write_sav(merged_data, spss_file_path, file_label=meta.file_label, variable_value_labels=meta.variable_value_labels)
```